# How do you translate the slug value of a page?

Tags: django, wagtail, django-modeltranslation

I'm trying to implement a language switcher, for which I'm using the Django recommended form:

```
    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
        <input name="language" type="hidden" value="{% if LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' %}es{% else %}en{% endif %}">
    </form>
```

My urls.py is set up like so:

```
urlpatterns = [

    # Wagtail urls
    re_path(r'^cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    re_path(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    # Django urls
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path(r'', include(wagtail_urls))
)
```

When I click to change my language, I am correctly forwarded to `/en/slug` or `es/slug`, depending on the language I have selected. However the actual slug value is not being translated. Since I have Spanish slugs for the Spanish pages, I am getting a 404 when I switch languages, because I am directed to the English slug value paired with the Spanish locale prefix (`es`).

I also tried using the `slugurl_trans` template tag, but that didn't seem to work (maybe because I'm not explicitly defining any URLs in my `i18n_patterns` call?).

Any guidance on this would be really helpful, as I've spent way too many hours on this!

Comment: Have you seen this in the Wagtail docs?  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/i18n/duplicate_tree.html?highlight=translation

Comment: @DanSwain Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I don't really think that's relevant, because it uses a duplicated page tree in order to implement language switching. Since I'm using `django-modeltranslation`, that should be provided out of the box, as far as I understand. With `django-modeltranslation`, if I access the `slug_es` link, the page renders using only the Spanish fields that I've set in the CMS.

Comment: Sure thing.  Don't know if this might be useful, but I just came across it:  https://github.com/springload/awesome-wagtail#translations.

Answer (score 0):

It has been long but I'm going to post an answer anyway, the best way to get rid of the different slugs problem is by using django signals like this

```
@receiver(pre_save)
def set_translated_slug_on_new_instance(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(instance, Page):
        instance.slug_es = instance.slug_en
```